# Spring Async Task running

Tags: spring, asynchronous

Spring 4.2.5
Java 7
Tomcat 7

I want to check my running async task. Check progess task while running. The controller as async task to run. 
hello.jsp contains jQuery function (timer) to see progress service (itRunning).

Controller

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Inject
    private RouteService routeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printRoute() {

        try  {

            Future<Plane> plane = routeService.execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return "hello";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/status")
    @ResponseBody
    public String fetchStatus() {
        --> Here return itRunning
    }   

}
```

Service

```
@Component("routeService")
public class RouteService {

    @Inject 
    private Route route;

    @Async
    public Future<Plane> execute() {

        Plane plane = route.execute();

        return new AsyncResult<Plane>(boat);

    }
}
```

AsyncTask

```
public class Route 
{

    private int itRunning=0;

    public Plane execute() {
        itRunning++;
    }

    public int getItRunning() {
        return itRunning;
    }

}
```

How can I read itRunning ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The your approach may be complex and probably not possible.

The key point hear is that in the your code below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/status")
@ResponseBody
public String fetchStatus() {
    --> Here return itRunning
}
```

for checking the progress will run in an another thread (the thread that will serve the web request) respect the thread the will serve the your async task.
For the your controller will be impossible to retrive informaton about the advancement of your async task.

A better approach may be use websocket in which the your asynctask publish the advancement. For how use web socket in Spring yon can see the official documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/ and https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ for see an example.

I hope that this can help you, because even if can appear complex use websocket solve many problem in a case as your.